# Workflow from Development to Production

Tags: workflow

I have created a Visual Studio 2010 Sequential Workflow and deploying it is pretty hassle free since Visual Studio can do that for me. 
Now I'm trying to deploy it to my production environment using Add- and Install-SPSolution via Management Shell, it seems to get deployed. However I can't find a way to associate it to my custom list. Am I missing a step here? 
Even just a pointer to the right path will be greatly appreciated. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Hi there see this sample:

http://addictedtosharepoint.com/2011/07/23/adding-a-sharepoint-workflow-association-to-a-list-with-powershell/

Cheers